# Unable to find/modify the Dockerfile of a Google App Engine Managed VM that uses a standard runtime (python27)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python, gae-module, managed-vm

I want to modify the Dockerfile of a Google App Engine managed VM that uses a standard runtime (python27).

I want to do this to add a C++ library that needs to be called to implement an HTTP request. This library is pretty much the only addition I need to the sandboxed python27 runtime.

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/#standard_runtimes) makes it quite clear that this is possible:

> Each standard runtime uses a default Dockerfile, which is supplied by the SDK. You can extend and enhance a standard runtime by adding new docker commands to this file.

[Elsewhere](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/tutorial/step2#dockerfile) they say that they Dockerfile of a standard runtime will be generated in the project directory:

> When you use gcloud to run or deploy a managed VM application based on a standard runtime (in this case Python27), the SDK will create a minimal Dockerfile using the standard runtime as a base image. You'll find this Dockerfile in your project directory...

This is the one I am supposed to modify according to the same page:

> Later steps in this tutorial will show you how to extend the capabilities of your runtime environment by adding instructions to the Dockerfile.

The problem is that when I do run my application on the dev server, I cannot find the Dockerfile anywhere, so I can't make any changes to it.

Has anyone managed to modify the standard runtime Dockerfile for Google App Engine? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the Dockerfile is generated only when using `gcloud preview app run` and not `dev_appserver.py`, which was what I was using.

I am however not able to modify the Dockerfile and run a custom managed VM. But that is a seperate error (`--custom_entrypoint` related).

This whole situation is a nightmare fueled by atrocious documentation and support. A warning for other developers considering Google App Engine.

Comment: I think this is managed vm and not appengine. But yeah I agree this is bizarre, I'm trying to change something in the generated Dockerfile, but I can't found one. And running `gcloud preview app run` is not allowed, it asks me to use dev_appserver.py

Answer (score 2):

To use google-api-python-client i had the same issue, cause I needed pycrypto. I always got the error:

> CryptoUnavailableError: No crypto library available

To solve this I created an instance start handler that installs all needed libs. It's ugly but it works.

app.yaml:

```
handlers:
- url: /_ah/start
  script: start_handler.app
```

start_handler.py

```
import webapp2
import logging
import os

class StartHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def execute(self, cmd):
    logging.info(os.popen("%s 2>&1" % cmd).read())

  def get(self):
    if not os.environ.get('SERVER_SOFTWARE','').startswith('Development'):
      self.execute("apt-get update")
      self.execute("apt-get -y install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python-dev")
      self.execute("pip install cryptography")
      self.execute("pip install pyopenssl")


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
                                ('/_ah/start', StartHandler)
                              ], debug=True)
```

Comment: That is a very very interesting approach. I would never have though about this. I ended up getting everything working with the Dockerfile, but it has the limitation that dev server does not support Dockerfiles, so I have to create a dev project on Google servers to do dev testing, which is a serious pain -- deploying the custom VM takes 10 min. It would be nice if I could get something like your setup working for my dev environment. Though for me, I am developing the C++ library myself, so I can't easily do a apt-get install of the library... But I will give it a hard look sometime.

Comment: As for your problem though, I'm actually also using pycrypto and I was able to get it working by simply adding pycrypto to the libraries section of the app.yaml. pycrypto is part of the App Engine's sandboxed python27 runtime as per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27?hl=en#runtime-libraries). You will also have to install pycrypto on the machine running dev_appserver.py. Does that not work for you?

Comment: See the "[Using Runtime-Provided Libraries with the Local Development Server](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27?hl=en#local-libraries)" section of the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, extending the Dockerfile in your app does not work the way it's purported in the Documentation ([Link](http://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/)). In fact, if there is a Dockerfile present you will get the following error:

```
"ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) There is a Dockerfile in the current directory, and the runtime field in /[...]/app.yaml is currently set to [runtime: python27]. To use your Dockerfile to build a custom runtime, set the runtime field in [...]/app.yaml to [runtime: custom]. To continue using the [python27] runtime, please omit the Dockerfile from this directory"
```

The only way I've been able to use a customized Dockerfile is using a custom runtime.

Google has a really good GitHub example for deploying Django to a managed VM using a custom Python runtime ([here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-django)).

Since you're using the custom runtime you'll have to implement health checking yourself. However, if you need to access Google APIs, Google has an example of how to set that up on GitHub ([here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-python)).

For help implementing health checking, or integrating with Google APIs you can follow the Google Compute Engine, Getting Started series of tutorials ([here](https://cloud.google.com/python/getting-started/hello-world)).